# Wordpress file upload no image

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, upload

I am working on a simple front end image upload in Wordpress. With this piece of code I can upload to the wordpress media section but I only upload the name and url of the file then, no image.

Does anyone know what I need to do to upload the image also?

My form:

```
<form id="dash_action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="file" name="file" /> 

   <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Save settings' ); ?>" />

</form><!--End dash_action-->
```

My PHP form handling:

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename($filename), null );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['subdir'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, 37 );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the upload is finished, image file is stored in temporary folder, and will be deleted if you do not copy it somewhere. You can get the file with

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

That will give you file path, which you can move with

```
move_uploaded_file();
```

where you need it.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer! But where in this Wordpress example do I need to do this?

Comment: I cant help you with WordPress code, I gave an example of PHP in general. So you need to find out how to store file where WordPress expects it, and process it further if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) states that "The file MUST be on the uploads directory". I've added a line to move the uploaded file into the uploads directory and changed the guid path.

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename($filename), null );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Move the uploaded file into the WordPress uploads directory
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $wp_upload_dir['path']  . '/' . $filename );

    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    $filename = $wp_upload_dir['path']  . '/' . $filename;

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, 37 );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['file']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );

$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . _wp_relative_upload_path( $upload['file'] ),
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $upload['file'] )),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload['file'],  $post_id);

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload['file'] );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail(  $post_id, $attach_id );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
```